# How to set the center as an offset from address in Google Static Maps API V2

Tags: offset, google-maps-static-api

I have a static map that is centered to **an address**:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=London,England&zoom=6&size=200x200&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false
```

And I would like to center the map to an offset of the address (scrolling the image).

If I would have centered the the image to **a latitude and a longitude** I could increase them to create the offset.

Is it possible to center to an offset from a textual address? Thanks!